# TypeError: animalData.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, redux

- I am getting an error `TypeError: animalData.slice is not a function`
- inside this method handleskyChange at the below line
  `let activeList = animalData.slice(skySlicestartNumber, skySliceEndNumber).map(data => {`
- I debugged and put console I was getting the values in animalData.
- so I put an if condition for undefined and empty
- but I am getting same error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet below.

```or-tag-here
handleskyChange = (skyNumber, skyItemsCount = 0) => {
    // console.log('handleChange ->', skyNumber);
    // console.log('skyItemsCount ->', skyItemsCount);
    skyNumber = skyNumber
        ? skyNumber.currentsky
            ? skyNumber.currentsky
            : skyNumber
        : 0;
    let itemsCount = Number(
        skyItemsCount === 0 ? this.state.skyItemsCount : skyItemsCount
    );
    let animalData = this.props.animalData.hasOwnProperty(
        'content'
    )
        ? this.props.animalData.content
        : this.props.animalData;
    let animalDataCount = this.props.animalData.hasOwnProperty(
        'totalCount'
    )
        ? this.props.animalData.totalCount
        : 0;
    this.setState({
        animalDataLength: animalDataCount,
    });
    let skySlicestartNumber = (skyNumber - 1) * itemsCount;
    let skySliceEndNumber = skySlicestartNumber + itemsCount;
    console.log("animalData--->", animalData);
    if (animalData != undefined && animalData != '') {
        console.log("inside if animalData--->", animalData);
        let activeList = animalData.slice(skySlicestartNumber, skySliceEndNumber).map(data => {
                data.expanded = false;
                return data;
            });
        this.setState({
            activeList: activeList,
        });
    }


    this.setState({ skyNumber: skyNumber, skyItemsCount: itemsCount });
    this.setState({ activesky: skyNumber });

    if (
        (Object.keys(this.props.rankSearch).length > 0 &&
            this.state.skyNumber != skyNumber) ||
        this.state.skyItemsCount != itemsCount
    ) {
        const house = {};
        house['skyNumber'] = skyNumber;
        house['skySize'] = itemsCount;
        {
            this.props.callContentCentralResults(
                this.props.rankSearch,
                'ranks',
                house
            );
        }
    }
};
```

**animalData output**

```or-tag-here
{
  "uniqueKey": 01222222222222222,
  "pin": true,
  "value": "{\"expanded\":true,\"value\":0,\"showpin\":true,\"groupCheckBoxValues\":[{\"label\":\" \\n        | "activeList\":[],\"skyItemsCount\":78,\"list\":[],\"skyNumber\":1,\"individualPaginateCheckboxes\":[],\"totalRecords\":6}",
  "skyNumber": 1,
  "skyItemsCount": 78
}
```

Comment: `animalData` is not an array, it is an object. So, you can't use `slice` on it.

Comment: Your animalData is an object while you're calling `slice()` function of an array.

Comment: As an aside, `setState()` is asynchronous; those state changes you make won't be reflected by `this.state` until after the function ends.

Comment: convert your object into arrays using `Object.values`, `Object.keys` or `Object.entries`

Comment: @all can you update in my code snippet so confusing :(

Answer (score 0):

slice is not working on object but only on arrays, to access keys try

```
Object.keys(animalData).slice(...)
```